# Send email when IIS web server not responding

Tags: iis, iis-7

Is there any way we can get email notification when IIS web server not responding or not working or any issues?.

Please let me know if we have any options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here's another one
http://www.pingdom.com

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of companies that will do this for you, some for free, some for a monthly fee.

Here are some:

http://www.monitor.us/index.jsp

http://www.site24x7.com/

or try googling "web server monitoring service"

Answer (score 0):

One cheaper option is through WMI scripting. Create a script that will listen on port 80 for the IP you want to track and if it doesn't respond in specified time, send an email to yourself. Also, email can be sent through a third party tool installed on the machine or default SMTP service. Of course you can schedule this script to run every minute or whatever time intervals you want. If you follow this route, it is highly beneficial if you create and schedule this task on a separate network.

Some links:

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/wmiexamples.php

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/162/managing-sites-with-iis39s-wmi-provider/